# StackPanel inside Grid - how to put its elements in different columns

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grid, stackpanel

Here's my code:

```
<Grid x:Name="SourceGrid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Headers" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="Tags" />



    <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllHeaders.Fields}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=SourceGrid, Path=DataContext.Tags}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

As you can see, I have a TextBlock and a ComboBox inside of a DataTemplate, which is inside of a StackPanel. What I want to do is put TextBlock in Column=0 of my grid, and a ComboBox into Column=1 of my grid. How can I do that? Grid.Column property is inaccessible in both TextBlock and ComboBox.

Comment: why not use `DataGrid` or `ListView` which have headers out-of-box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is your new layout:

```
<Grid x:Name="SourceGrid">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   Text="Headers" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                   Grid.Column="1"
                   Text="Tags" />

        <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1"
                      Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllHeaders.Fields}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid x:Name="SourceGrid">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                                   Grid.Column="0" />
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Tags, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Grid},AncestorLevel=2}}"
                                  Grid.Column="1" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
```

or

```
  <Grid x:Name="SourceGrid">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   Text="Headers" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                   Grid.Column="1"
                   Text="Tags" />

        <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1"
                      Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllHeaders.Fields}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid x:Name="SourceGrid">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                                   Grid.Column="0" />
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Tags, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"
                                  Grid.Column="1" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: It works as it should, but one problem occured: when I use your layout my ComboBox doesn't have any content. When I use my layout it has content as it should (it's bound to DataContext.Tags). Why is that? Your layout doesn't change binding in any way.

Comment: OK, fixed this - you added Grid inside of my DataTemplate and you gave it name property, which was already used by the parent Grid.

Comment: Yes, because I haven't paid attention for DataContext.
I suppose not it is OK.
I corrected my answer.